# Magento Create Categories with REST API

Tags: java, rest, magento, categories

I'm doing an integration with Magento for Openbravo ERP based in Java.
I decided to do it by REST API because I'm more familiar with it, but to start, I see that I can not create categories through a request.
I've been looking for a couple of days on the internet and I have found a little information, and when I do, is to extend the API directly.

Is there any way to create categories / attributes without extending the API?
Or do I stop wasting time and choose to do it  with SOAP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this method isn't supported with out of the box regardless of service you're using.

```
/**
 * Product category assign is not available
 *
 * @param array $data
 */
protected function _create(array $data)
{
    $this->_critical(self::RESOURCE_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
}
```